# Agreeing on a single shortened nomenclature?

Tags: discussion, site-name

I've noticed across various stack exchange sites that when they refer to their own stack exchange on their site, they'll shorten the name to something similar to either:

EE.SE (Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange) OR Tex.Sx (LaTeX Stack Exchange)

Essentially they'll do XX.SE or XX.SX which has the possibility to generate some confusion for new users.

Have I not visited enough sites and just noticed an outlier or would it be beneficial for Stack Exchange sites to agree on a shortened name nomenclature?

Comment: Follow the magic links--`[meta.se]` => [meta.se]

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is something we need to be 100% consistent about unless SO wishes to specify their preferred way of abbreviating.

However, I prefer XX SE because XX.SE looks like a Swedish domain name and XX.SX and XX SX are variants that I rarely see used.

I cannot see a reason for the period (.) being placed between the site name abbreviation and the abbreviation used for Stack Exchange.

Comment: Oh good point! I hadn't thought about the swedish deal

Answer (score 1):

There is a little bit of a standard if you look at it, but it's mostly for beta sites. The site favicon is generally what sets it. For example, here's the logo for Software Recommendations, Worldbuilding, and even elementary OS:

[image]
[image]
[image]

You'll generally see Software Recommendations be abbreviated  to SR, but I don't generally see the same for Worldbuilding. It almost varies by site, and whether the site community accepts to call themselves the "shortened" name.